# Firebase Admin SDK handle expired access token

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core, firebase-cloud-messaging, firebase-admin

I'm using the Firebase Admin SDK with ASP.net Core and because we are using ***workload identity federation*** instead of the service account key json file i'm creating my FirebaseApp instance this way:

```
FirebaseApp.Create(new AppOptions()
{
    Credential = GoogleCredential.FromAccessToken(serviceAccountToken),
    ProjectId = projectNo
})
```

Where "serviceAccountToken" is a Google Access Token received in a previous step.
This works like intended, but the access token i'm using expires after 1 hour.

My problem: I couldn't find a way to update the existing FirebaseApp instance with a new access token. My best approach is to use `FirebaseApp.DefaultInstance.Delete()` to dispose the current instance and then create a new one, but that seems a bit heavy for just updating the access token.

Is there a better approach?

**Update:**

My next attempt was simply to assign a new token after the token expired via `FirebaseApp.DefaultInstance.Options.Credentials = GoogleCredential.FromAccessToken (newToken)`, but the new credentials are not taken into account.

After reading through the 'google-api-dotnet-client' source code, I noticed that `GoogleCredential.FromAccessToken` uses  `AccessTokenCredentials` internally (see [github](https://github.com/googleapis/google-api-dotnet-client/blob/20fe608c5e19d6214edad67c3bc6f343b405a151/Src/Support/Google.Apis.Auth/OAuth2/AccessTokenCredential.cs)). So I tried to write my own implementation of AccessTokenCredential and implement a refresh function there, unfortunately the interfaces for it are all declared internal.
In the end, there is still no good solution.